# How to display error on PHP Plates templating engine

Tags: php, templates, error-handling

I am trying to set up [platesphp](https://platesphp.com/) for one of my projects.

One of the methods in the model checks for the email address supplied by a new user and tells if the email they trying to use exists or not.

Something like

```
class UserModel extends BaseModel
{
    public $errors = [];

    public function validate()
    {
        if (filter_var($this->request->post['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) === false) {
            $this->errors[] = 'Invalid email';
        }
        if ($this->emailExists($this->request->post['email'])) {
            $this->errors[] = 'Email already exist';
        }
    }

    protected function emailExists($email)
    {
        $sql = 'SELECT * FROM user_account WHERE email = :email';
        -----
        -----
        $stmt->execute();
        return $stmt->fetch() !== false;
    }
}
```

and in the controller

```
public function register()
{
    $this->load->getModel('UserModel');

    if ($this->model_UserModel->registerUser($this->request->post)) {
        echo "Success ... load (redirect) second page";
    } else {
        $data ['error'] = $this->model_UserModel->errors;
        echo $this->template->render('home/home', $data);
    }
}
```

If the email exists and I var dump $data ['error'] it says "Email already Exist" as defined in the validate method in the UserModel.

Now, I am trying to get the error message on my home template by adding these lines on the tpl file

```
<?php if (!empty($this->e($errors))): ?>
    <?php foreach($errors as $error): ?>
        <li><?=$this->e($error)?></li>
    <?php endforeach ?>
<?php endif;?>
```

But now if I click on the register page the template says

**Notice: Undefined variable: errors in C:\xampp\htdocs\vem\App\Views\template\register\registeruser.tpl on line 14**

How do I move forward?

I even tried setting the `$this->e($error) = ''` but naa, shows another error.

Comment: `$errors` is not defined. That's what the error message say. You might want to change `$data ['error']` to `$data['errors']`. Looks like a "typo question" to me, and schould be closed.

Answer (score 1):

On your controller, you're setting variable `error`, but in template, you're accessing variable `errors` (with `s`).
Try with

```
<?php if (@$error)): ?>
    <?php foreach($error as $e): ?>
        <li><?=$this->e($e)?></li>
    <?php endforeach ?>
<?php endif;?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need use `error` not `errors`:

```
<?php if (!empty($this->e($error))): ?>
    <?php foreach($error as $error_item): ?>
        <li><?=$this->e($error_item)?></li>
    <?php endforeach ?>
<?php endif;?>
```